# Database of adult sites

Tags: data-request

I would like to ban all adult content in my DNS/VPN service and I wouldn't like to outsource this. Is there a list of URLs I can use as a blacklist in my routers/servers?

Format doesn't matter and if it would be actively maintained that would be nice.

Comment: I googled "porn site database" and got a list of sites. Careful, though, you might accidentally see some pornography.

Comment: @moonman239 I see sites that are a collections for those who want to find this type of content. I'm looking for an actual database with millions of rows so I can ban the biggest set possible (I know I can't ban _all_ of them).

Answer (score 3):

There is quite a bit on the topic turned up by a simple google search:

http://urlblacklist.com/?sec=home

http://www.squidblacklist.org/

http://dsi.ut-capitole.fr/blacklists/index_en.php

https://blog.opendns.com/2010/06/23/introducing-familyshield-parental-controls/